# What does the phrase *order of tens* mean?

Tags: meaning

I've encountered the following paragraph in a paper

> Fortunately, the task can become much simpler if we restrict the
> domain to the set of all graphs on maximum k nodes, where k is fairly
> small (in practice up to the order of tens).

I was wondering what *order of tens* means in this context? Up to 100?

---

What I found in the dictionary:

MATHEMATICS
the degree of complexity of an equation, expression, etc., as denoted by an ordinal number.

Comment: What did you find when you looked up *order* in a dictionary or three? Did you find anything which might match that usage? What did you find which was close and didn't entirely fit? Please show your research.

Comment: @AndrewLeach No.

Comment: I would personally read that as limiting k to below 40, and probably below 30. It's not an exact number (obviously, since "much simpler" is not an exact descriptor).

Comment: Research aside, this is going to be sticky. Certanly 'the order of tens' comes between units and hundreds, but 'of the order of tens' carries, I feel, a pragmatic weighting to the low tens (though obviously it means literally the interval [10,100[ (though a limitation to integers may be implied).

Comment: I guess "No" wasn't the answer to "Please show your research." You found something in Oxford/Lexico (although I think their sense 5 is nearer the meaning); did you look in more than dictionary?

Comment: The answer to "Please show your research." was to show my research. The answer to "Did you find anything which might match that usage?" was "No". The answer to "What did you find which was close and didn't entirely fit?" was "MATHEMATICS the degree of complexity of an equation, expression, etc., as denoted by an ordinal number." Feel free to comment if you have any more questions.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your research.  It's also helpful to include a link to the definition you're quoting, and state which dictionary you consulted.  Also, questions citing two different dictionaries with somewhat differing results will generally be received even better.  I'm sharing this because I had to learn certain things about this site the hard way (in the early days I got some harsh feedback, and at that time I didn't realize I should flag such things). / Hard to tell if the author meant *up to about 80 or 90* or something smaller.